# Jump to Address after Branching in For Loop in MIPS

Tags: c, byte, branch, mips, bit

I am trying to code a program that checks if the 16 bits in an integer is a one or zero. I chose to implement this by shifting right one bit 15 times and checking if the first bit in each shift is a zero or non zero. Then, if the first bit is a 1, I increment an integer.

I made some code in C that represents a non-user input version of my code.

```
int j = 100;
int checker = 0;
int count = 0;
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
  checker = j & 0x1;
  if (checker > 0)
    count++;
  j = (j >> 1);
}
```

My code in MIPS:

```
  .data
    userprompt: .asciiz "Enter positive integer: "
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
  .text
  .globl main

main:   
  li  $v0, 4              # System call: Display string
  la  $a0, userprompt     # Load string userprompt for output
  syscall

  li  $v0, 5              # System call: Read integer
  syscall
  move $s0, $v0           # Store integer from v0 to s0

  move $s1, $s0           # s1 = s0
  li $t0, 0               # t0 = 0
  jal chk_zeros           # Run function: chk_zeroes

  li  $v0, 1              # System call: Read integer
  move  $a0, $t2         # Store integer from t2 to a0
  syscall
  li $v0, 10              # System call: quit
  syscall 

chk_zeros:
  bgt $t0, 15, exitchk    # t0 <= 15
  addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Add one to t0

  andi $t1, $s1, 0x1      # Check if first bit is non-zero, store in t1
  bgtz $t1, chk_zerosadd  # If t1 >= 0

  j chk_zeros

chk_zerosadd:
  addi $t2, $t2, 1        # Add one to t2
  jr $ra                  # Return to after the if statement (does not work!)

exitchk:
  jr $ra
```

What I am having trouble with is making chk_zerosadd return to after the branching statement. jr $ra seems to return me to my main function in chk_zerosadd.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this was to check the first 16 bits in a 32 bit integer.

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, don't do it as a comment, instead *edit your question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bgtz` doesn't place the next PC address into the return address register, so `jr $ra` won't return to the instruction after the branching statement. You can either use `bgtzal` (branch if greater than zero and link), which will give you the behaviour you are looking for, or else you can re-arrange your code so that you branch over the add, instead of branching to it, like this:

```
    andi $t1, $s1, 0x1      # Check if first bit is non-zero, store in t1
    beq $t1, chk_zerosskipadd  # Jump if $t1 is zerp
    addi $t2, $t2, 1        # Add one to t2
chk_zerosskipadd:
    # continue execution...

    srl $s1, $s1, 1         # j = (j >> 1);
    j chk_zeros
```